# Curve fitting on non-linear ODE data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, regression, mathematical-modeling, curves, regression-analysis

> **Background**

The graph below was generated by a set non-linear ODEs.

For those of you who might want to know:  It shows the maximum distance achieved by a cylinder when fired at a specified initial velocity (different graphs) vs the angle of the shot.

[image: graph curve fit]

I need help with the method for finding a single equation to describe these graphs.
I require an equation of the form y = f(d,v) where y is the maximum distance atainable ; d is the degrees elevation above the horisontal ; and v is the initial velocity.

> **What I have done thus far**

About 80 data points were generated for each of the four initial velocities.

For each function:

I guessed a function and initial values for that function.  I calculated the absolute difference between the simulation data and the data generated from the function.  All of these errors were then summed.  Excels built-in solver was used to minimize the total error by changing the parameters of the equation.  This was repeated until convergence was reached.

An equation of the form

$$ y = A*exp(B*(d+C)) + D*exp(E*(d+C))+F $$

was found.

*For those of you who want to test it out:*

For the highest peak curve ;  A = -26.8995 , B = 0.040039 , C = -21 , D = -0.59297 , E = -0.30423 , F = 400.2593 ; d = [1:80]*.

After this was done for all 4 graphs, the parameter values were moved to a different sheet.   Each parameter was seperately graphed vs the four initial velocities ,v.  E.g.  A1-4 vs v1-4

It was then found that a 3rd order polynomial fit most of the data very well (obviously).  I found it to be acceptable since the initial velocities that I used are 4 equally spaced values between the minimum and maximum possible values for initial velocity.  Interpolating between them on the calculated curve will yield respectable results.

Thus the parameters of the first equation was found to be a 3rd order polynomial in v.

so finally;

$$ y = A(v)*exp(B(v)*(d+C(v))) + D(v)*exp(E(v)*(d+C(v)))+G(v) $$

This equation has 24 constants

This equation performed brilliantly for the most part.  The maximum percentage difference to the ODE model was ~23%.  Upon graphing the errors vs the degrees for all 4 initial velocities, it was seen that the error percentage is within the generally acceptable 5% range with the condition that the degrees are higher than 10 and lower that 75.  This still leaves me with more than 80% valid values for the angle of launch.  Totally acceptable for me.

I could theoretically curve fit the error to find error = f(d) for each graph and then fit the constants to curve as well, so that the final error = f(d,v).  This multiplied with the double exponential function will effectively reduce my error to zero.

However, this method took a large amount of time to complete.

> **The question**

How can I perform similar calculations on a much larger data set and possibly increase my valid data intervals?  E.g. 500 intervals of degrees and 100 intervals of initial velocity?  My method requires alot of "hand" work.  I am confident that there exist other methods that will deliver a similar result with much less effort on my part.

Comment: I think you are running a real risk of overfitting this. At the very least $B$ and $E$ are redundant (because you can do $A\exp(B)\exp(d+C)$ equivalent to $A_2\exp(d+C)$), and you should have a good reason for having two exponential terms. Why are you not simply doing 2D interpolation?

Comment: I will eventually use the formula to solve for certain variables, given some initial condition.  Running the ODEs repeatedly until a solution to my problem is obtained is highly impractical because this model will be implemented on a really small electronic board.  I need to have a minimum of 5% deviation from the ode model for the project to be practical.  Using interpolation will work, but only very closely to the available data points otherwise I am certain that the error would be larger than 5%.

Comment: Will you precompute the functions and just calculate the value using your board, or does it have to do all the data collection and fitting too? You can set this problem up as a minimisation problem, minimise the error by varying the constants. The problem is that it is a large search space (although you definitely have some unnecessary terms at the moment). Have you tried replacing one of the exponential terms with a polynomial term? Have you looked at the physics (at a simplified level) to get a solution, which you can use to inform the choice of functions in your model equation?

Comment: I did set it up as a minimization problem.  Minimizing the error between the ode data and data generated by the double exponential.  Using a 10th order or so polynomial will probably work, but I feel that the double exponential works almost perfectly.  What I eventually plan to do, is to expand my ODE model to account for more forces acting on the cylinder.  Before I do that, I need to make sure that I have a method of reducing the odes to a few equations.  My odes calculated the position, velocity and acceleration at every time step.  This is unnecessary for me.

Comment: I am only interested in the final values e.g how far did it go, how high, what is the travel time.   I am trying to fit for those.  I am trying to replicate the effect caused by MRSI (multiple round, simultaneous impact) that is used by militaries around the world.  Firing your first projectile at a high angle, with high velocity.  The second projectile is fired at a lower angle and lower velocity, etc.  If done right, a couple of projectiles will land at the same distance and exact same time.  The effect of this is of course devastating.  Given a certain distance, I want to know

Comment: which degrees and initial velocities will provide me with a MRSI effect on the target.

Comment: To answer some of your second question, it will not do any data collection what so ever.  I will input only the distance I want to achieve, and it will output possible solutions for the problem (with certain constraints of course, otherwise the solutions would be infinite)

Comment: From the basic projectile motion equations, maximum height goes like $v^2\sin^2(\theta)$ (initial velocity $v$, angle $\theta$). So, in your equation for maximum height, you want a term that looks like $v^2\sin^2(\theta)$ along with terms that allow for corrections to give you the right results. Starting with a more realistic model equation that models the underlying physics more closely should allow you to get a better fit.

Comment: You could also considering looking into efficient interpolation schemes, given you can pre-compute a lot of things, it should be quite feasible I would imagine.

Comment: The graph that I added was given by my ODEs accounting for wind resistance in both dimensions.  This cause the "vertical" ode to be non linear.  I have yet to add projectile spin and the accompanying magnus force or the buoyancy force (which is most likely negligible), and, a third dimension of movement.  That is why I cant run the ODEs repeatedly on my small board.  Actually, running it on my PC will take a few minutes to hours even.  Do you know of any interpolation schemes that might work for this?

Comment: It does depend a bit on how many variables you will be controlling. If you only control velocity and launch angle, you only need to do 2D interpolation, which should be OK. It depends on how long your ODE model takes to solve, as to how much time you should invest in improving your curve fitting or generating data to interpolate. I would try your original approach with a function like $y=Av^2\sin^2(\theta)+B\exp(\theta+C)+D\exp(v+E)+Fv\theta+Gv^2+H\theta^2+Iv+J\theta+K$, (or something, I'm not too sure).

Comment: For example, imagine you didn't have any air resistance, spin, etc., so you have pure parabolic motion. If you wanted to find an equation for the maximum height, you would do $Av^2\sin^2)(\theta)$, and solve a minimisation problem to find $A$. You wouldn't use $A(v)\exp(\theta+B(v))+C(v)\exp(\theta+D(v))+E(v)$ because it wouldn't be able to give a quadratic dependence of the maximum height upon $v$ or $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: But then I would end up in the same situation I am in now.  I have ALOT of data points, about 40k points.  Minimizing the error between 40k data points by changing the constants in the equation will take way to long with my current method

Comment: But once you know the constants it's fine, and the minimisation is likely to be computationally easier, because you'd be starting with a better guess and the error should behave more nicely.

Comment: I dont completely understand what you think I should I do.  I as far as I understand, I have to "guess" a function and the values of the constants in it, then use that formula to calculate the maximum height for example.  Then, I will minimize the error between the calculated values and the real values obtained from the ode, by changing the constants.  Doing this for 40k data points and 24 constants is impractical with my method

Comment: It is a complicated question, it's hard to answer. I'll try and write an answer demonstrating my point.

Comment: Instead of a graph, a numerical table should be more usefull to make some tests.